# PHPExcel Piechart legends with fix length

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I have issue in setting the width of the legend lables.
I can show them but not able to show them as per expectation.

[Currently it is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jg3y.png)

[I want the Legend to be displayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtPKi.png)

My code

```
//NOTE Layer for charts
$layout=new \PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout->setShowVal(true);
$layout->setShowPercent(true);
// Set series in the plot area
$pa=new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout, array($ds));
// Set legend
$legend=new \PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(\PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_BOTTOM, NULL, false);
//Create Chart
$chart= new \PHPExcel_Chart('chart1',$title,$legend,$pa,true,0,NULL, NULL);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('K'.$chart_index);
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('S'.($chart_index+20));
$ews2->addChart($chart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for my problem.

I have just created array with expected label;

```
$pie_label = array($ea->getActiveSheet()->getCell("E".$i)->getValue(),$ea->getActiveSheet()->getCell("F".$i)->getValue(),$ea->getActiveSheet()->getCell("G".$i)->getValue(),$ea->getActiveSheet()->getCell("H".$i)->getValue());
```

and append it at end of the funtion of PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues,and converted my second parameter of function to null.

```
$spec_label = array(new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', null, NULL, 1,$pie_label),);
```